# Convert normal table to temporal table on production database without downtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-tables

I am inside a production environment and I'd like to transform a normal table (a huge table, with million rows and continuous writes) into a temporal table. I know how to do that, but I'd like to know what can happen.

Will the table be locked or not?
How long could this operation last?
Is there an option (like ONLINE=ON) to avoid the table lock?

Comment: Notwithstanding that these questions have independent answers -- if you have no testing environment to simply try out these things before doing it on production so you know what to expect, you're doing it wrong. At the very least, even if resources for a full copy are lacking, you could copy a (substantial enough) part of the data to an instance running Developer edition.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Of course I have a test database on which I can test this before going into production (and it is almost aligned to the production database). The only difference is that on my local testing database I don't have the load of reads and writes I have on production database, and this can be a determining factor.

Comment: Not for locking, at least -- even a single transaction would be enough to check if the temporal conversion operation locks the table for the entire duration. Of course a more substantial simulation of data access would be better -- even that would not be hard to write, though, at the core two `SET NOCOUNT ON` sessions with `INSERT` and `SELECT` and a `GO 10000` are already better than nothing.